# Dynamic schemes SAML 2.0 for IdentityServer4 with IAuthenticationSchemeProvider

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, saml-2.0

I'm trying to setup IdentityServer4 to work with multiple external IdPs which are added dynamically with the help of `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider`'s `AddScheme` method.

I've successfully done it for `OpenIdConnect` IdPs, but having a bit of a trouble with `Saml2p` based IdPs.
Following [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/tree/master/samples/DynamicSchemes) sample, I followed the same logic for Saml2p:

Injected `IOptionsMonitorCache<Saml2pAuthenticationOptions>` and :

```
if (await _schemeProvider.GetSchemeAsync(scheme) == null)
            {
                _schemeProvider.AddScheme(new AuthenticationScheme(scheme, scheme, typeof(Saml2pAuthenticationHandler)));
            }
            else
            {
                 _saml2pOptionsCache.TryRemove(scheme);
            }
            _saml2pOptionsCache.TryAdd(scheme, samlOptions);
```

And I'm getting an exception:

``` Unable to resolve service for type 'Rsk.AspNetCore.Authentication.Saml2p.Factories.ISamlFactory``1[IdentityServer4.Saml.Generators.Interfaces.IServiceProviderMetadataGenerator]' while attempting to activate 'Rsk.AspNetCore.Authentication.Saml2p.Saml2pAuthenticationHandler'. ```

I am not sure if i should setup some additional configurations regarding Saml while adding the scheme, any help appreciated.

Edit:
I am using Rsk NuGet for SAML 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `AddSaml2p` registers a load of dependencies as well as the authentication handler.

I would either call `AddSaml2p` somewhere in your code or register the required dependencies yourself like so:

```
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlFactory<IServiceProviderMetadataGenerator>, 
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlFactory<ISaml2SingleSignOnRequestGenerator>, Saml2SingleSignOnRequestGeneratorFactory>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlFactory<ISaml2SingleLogoutRequestGenerator>, Saml2SingleLogoutRequestGeneratorFactory>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlFactory<ISaml2SingleSignOnResponseValidator>, Saml2SingleSignOnResponseValidatorFactory>();

builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlBindingService, SamlBindingService>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlSigningService, SamlSigningService>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<IDateTimeService, SystemClockDateTimeService>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlTimeComparer, SamlTimeComparer>();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<ISamlCorrelationStore, CookieCorrelationStore>();
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott, I added AddSaml2p on startup with some default options, and the dynamic schemes seem to be added now. Thank you, again!